# Why does Bayes Factor go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, bayes-factors

Why does Bayes Factor go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity when considering a bilateral alternative hypothesis?

The Bayes factor is $BF=\frac{postodds}{prior odds}$, and since the prior odds are not impacted by $n$, this must mean that the posterior odds go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity. I just don't see why this is the case.

Comment: For essentially the same reason that the likelihood ratio provides a convergent test.  Check for [Laplace approximation](http://www.astro.ubc.ca/people/jvw/ASTROSTATS/Answers/Chap7_2/ans_7_2_6.pdf) to see an intuitive explanation.

Comment: "consistent" test?